# Dock a window to the side

Tags: unity

I'm struggling to find the right words to google, so forgive me if this has already been answered.

I want to "dock" a window to the side.  I'm using Zim to take notes and my setup has just a single monitor.  I want to put Zim on the right 1/4 of my screen and have it stay there always.  I want other applications to treat the space that Zim is taking up as being reserved... meaning if I maximize Chrome, I don't want it to fill the whole screen, but just the left 3/4.

I was able to get close using "Always on top" and "Always visible on all workspaces".  The only part I can't get is for other applications to treat that space as "taken".

There is a similar functionality in Windows using OneNote.  Basically you can just dock the note taking application on the side.  It seems that Linux can do anything... surely there is some easy way to do this that I'm just missing.

Comment: Linux can do anything, but that doesn't mean it's easy. Why not just drag the windows so they snap to each half of the screen and then drag them out or in to the desired size?

Comment: Chrome will remember where it was last placed and sized so you would only have to do it once. That said I have conky on the right side of my screen like your notes so whatever solution works for you I would like to implement too. So +1 for your question.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Good point about it not necessarily being easy.  To answer your question, I'm working in about six other applications and jumping back and forth between the applications and between workspaces.  Sometimes I want to have the applications themselves shown side-by-side, so I'm already using the functionality to snap them together on the left and right of the screen, and then I have to resize them.  In other words, I'll be doing this a lot, so I'd like it to be as easy as possible.

Comment: Well I'm sure it's possible, but I don't see easy. Let me see if our script-guru has something.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Unfortunately every time I close my laptop it resets to the optimal resolution of 3200x1800 and tosses Chrome into the middle of the screen when I run my bash script to reset to the resolution that I prefer.  Thanks for voting up my question.

Comment: I'll write a script that can place windows as you want , it'll require custom shortcut though. What are your requirements aside from placing one window into 1/4 and others into 3/4 of the screen ?

Comment: @serg Thanks for helping.  I'm not sure how detailed you want the requirements to be or what exactly I can ask for.  Here's a shot at some requirements.

When I run the script, launch Zim and put it on the right 1/4 of the screen.  Zim will always be on top.  Zim will always be on all workspaces.  Please enforce that via the script.

All programs that aren't Zim will treat the left 3/4 (excluding the left-most Unity launcher) as "the desktop".  (I have my Unity Launcher along the left, and my task bar/menu bar at the top.)

When Zim isn't running, applications can use the full screen.

Comment: @Serg saving the day again! <Super>+F for full screen would be a viable short cut and top-left of 0,0 and bottom right of 1700,1080 would work for me, but should be configurable depending on screen resolution such as Mary would need bottom right coordinates ~ 2500,1800. Then it can be tweaked to exact pixel size. Which ever window has focus would be psuedo-maximized right? and then the normalize button could be clicked later right?

Comment: @MaryGreyFox  are you using default Ubuntu with Unity desktop ?

Comment: @serg Yes, I am.

Comment: @MaryGreyFox very well. I'll be working on the script over next couple of days. Expect it posted on Tuesday, maybe Wednesday

Comment: May need a couple more days - things outside AskUbuntu require a bit more of my attention. I do have a draft of the script , but it will require some more polishing first.

Comment: Here's link to the draft: https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/b78b12cd32537f5d94f084fe00d9e092. So far it only resizes window to certain fraction of size. Eventually, it will also be placing the window in proper location. Usage is `python 3-4-placement.py 0.75` for 3/4 resize. Once I'll add placement and proper command-line options, I'll write full answer.